# How to move a svn folder from one location to another

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a folder 'Folder3' inside another folder called 'Folder2'.
Now i want to switch 'Folder3' to the parallel location of 'Folder2'.

Example:

```
Current:../Folder1/Folder2/Folder3 
Desired:../Folder1/Folder3
```

I want to move Folder3 to Desired path as mentioned above with the commit history.

Comment: Its not clear what youre asking... If you want to move Folder3 in the hierarchy then you want to do `svn mv` and then commit. If you want to switch Folder3 in your working copy to a different branch then you would use `svn switch`

Comment: My question is very clear, whether history remains or not??? please answer this if you know.

Comment: Swtich doesnt commit anything so your history would remain the same. Switch just switches the target part of the WC to a new remote repository.

Comment: @prodigitalson Can you please answer my question? I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use [`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html). That updates the project to use a different URL. You use `switch` to move between branches (similar to a `checkout`). What you want to do is actually move files around and then commit your changes, since you are changing file locations. For that you want to use [`svn move`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) and then `commit` your changes.